# Как в python3 получить код символа аналогичный charCodeAt в JS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

Есть строка зашифрованная с помощью xor. В строке есть подстрока "".

Если идти по ней циклом в JS выдаётся одно:

```js
var testS = "";
for (var i = 0; i < testS.length; i++) {
    console.log(i + ": " + testS.charCodeAt(i));
}

0: 55388
1: 56499
2: 55305
3: 56498
4: 55307
5: 56546
```

Если идти по ней циклом в python выдаётся другое:

```py
testS = ""

for i in range(0, len(testS)):
    print(f"{i}: {ord(testS[i])}")

0: 159923
1: 74930
2: 77026
```

Как в python получать числа аналогичные выводу в JS? Разница в числах и их количестве ломает весь последующий текст.

Comment: Ну так Python правильные коды выдал (можете сами [проверить](https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/)): 3 символа - 3 кода. Это у JS лажа какая-то...

Comment: [Тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) написано, что для JS вообще по два кода надо брать от `charCodeAt(i)` и `charCodeAt(i+1)` и потом вычислять полный код символа.

Comment: Я не могу повлиять на способ кодирования, так что для меня не так важно кто прав, мне нужно чтобы было одинаково.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Конвертируем в байты в кодировке utf16
- Отрезаем заголовок (2 байта)
- Берём байты попарно и считаем из них 16-битные слова

```
testS = ""
l = list(bytes(testS, 'utf-16'))[2:]
for i, c in enumerate([(b<<8)|a for a,b in list(zip(l,l[1:]))[::2]]):
    print(f"{i}: {c}")
```

Результат:

```
0: 55388
1: 56499
2: 55305
3: 56498
4: 55307
5: 56546
```

Comment: Добавьте вывод, который получается в итоге, если он совпадает с выводом в вопросе, то и хорошо, как-раз убедиться

Comment: Добавил. Хотя особого смысла в этом не было, ибо если результат совпадает, то зачем повторяться. А если нет - то это не никак не могло бы считаться ответом. :)

Answer (score 5):

Пока не нашёл как всё это толком прямо всё кодом на питоне показать, но в общем основной смысл в том, что `JavaScript` печатает каждый символ как два отдельных числа, причём строка берётся в кодировке `UTF-16BE`, а вот `Python` воспринимает каждый символ как одно число и кодировка берётся `UTF-32BE`, в чём можно убедиться, посмотрев 16-ричные коды первого символа вашей строки например на [этой странице](https://unicode-table.com/en/270B3/) или [этой](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+270B3).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

16-ричные коды чисел из вашего вопроса для сверки со страницей выше:

```
print(hex(159923))
# 0x270b3

print(hex(55388),hex(56499))
# 0xd85c 0xdcb3
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не исключаю, что у вас и файлы, из которых взят код, в разных кодировках, так что виноват в расхождении показаний не только язык, возможно.

Answer (score 0):

По крайней мере, с китайскими иероглифами функция [ord()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) из Python ведёт себя точно так же, как и метод [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) из JavaScript и метод [unicode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qchar.html#unicode)() из Qt C++. Следующий код на Python, JavaScript и Qt C++ выдаёт одинаковый результат:

```
20320
22909
19990
30028
65281
```

Python:

```py
str = "你好世界！"

for s in str:
    print(ord(s))
```

JavaScript:

```js
const str = "你好世界！";

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    console.log(str.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

Qt C++:

```cpp
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
public:
    Widget() {
        QString str = "你好世界！";
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            qDebug() << (int) str[i].unicode();
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```